# How to install PHPUnit with WAMP?

Tags: php, phpunit, wamp

I'm a newbie programmer and I have tried for an embarrassingly long time to get PHPUnit set up and working with WAMP. I have read the documentation and went through various sites to see what I'm doing wrong, but I give up! I need someone to explain this to me in simple terms.

I've probably seen all the guides on how to set it up, but feel free to link me to something you believe is foolproof!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this blog : http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.com/2011/04/installing-phpunit-on-windows.html

This setup is for Windows. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why is setting this up so complicated?

Comment: I think this has gotten a lot easier over the last year.

Comment: This answer is deprecated. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Comment: composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=5.1.*" https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer

Answer (score 4):

Also check this out, may be useful http://www.mark-leong.com/installing-php-and-phpunit-on-windows-7/

// adding required pear channels

> pear channel-update pear.php.net
>
> pear upgrade-all
>
> pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
>
> pear channel-discover components.ez.no
>
> pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
>
> pear update-channels

// performing install

> pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit

If everything ok, check whether phpunit have been installed by putting  in command line

> phpunit -v

If you encountered any errors or interrupted installing

> pear clear-cache

may be usefull in that case.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: i try to install using this link but get this error "C:\php>phpunit -v
PHPUnit 3.4.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

unrecognized option -- v"

Comment: This is deprecated. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Answer (score 2):

1) download https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
2) run it via php phpunit.phar

Btw if that file ever goes away you can look at the original directions here:  https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using composer. It can be used per project, but also 'globally'.

Make a folder on your C drive called 'globalpackages', then cd into it from the command line.

run 'composer require phpunit/phpunit'

once that finishes run 'composer install'

once that finishes you can check the contents of C:\globalpackages\vendor\phpunit' and should see two phpunit files, one of them a bat.

Add C:\globalpackages\vendor\phpunit to your system path and then you will be able to run phpuni from anywhere on your system.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is the fastests and easiest way.

1. Make sure you have wamp with WAMP with PHP 7 installed as phpunit requires PHP7 to work! or at least 6.2
2. Go to folder 
   wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10
   (wherever you installed your wamp - BEWARE last folder is name of PHP version you have so it might be different then above )

We will be working in this folder during entire installation. So if I say edit file etc it means in this folder.

3. Download newest version of phpunit from https://phpunit.de/

At the time of writing this I get version phpunit 6.2 and php7.0.10
4. Copy downloaded file to wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10 folder
For me it's: phpunit-6.2.2.phar
for you it might be different version.

5. Now **change** name of the **phpunit-6.2.2.phar to phpunit.phar**
6. Now make sure you have added your php to PATH in  Environment Variables
   To do this on Windows 10 and Windows 8

6a. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)

6b. Click the Advanced system settings link.

6c. Click Environment    Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment    variable and select it. Click Edit. If the    PATH environment       variable does not exist, click New.

6d. In the Edit System       Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the     PATH environment variable. Paste location of    your PHP. For me it would be:     D:\AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10

(if in PATH there was other command or path just add ";" at the end. For exmaple:

%someOtherCommand%; D:\AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10)

6e. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

7. In cmd (to run cmd go to search in Windows and type cmd.exe and click Enter)
   go to folder wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10
   (to go to folder type for example `cd D:\AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10`)
8. now once you are in this folder run this command in cmd:
   echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd
9. now run this command:

`phpunit`

you should get list of all commands available in phpunit

now run this:

`phpunit --check-version`

you will get info what phpunit version you have and if you are using the newest version.

10. if this doesn't work go to wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10
11. Edit file phpunit.bat
12. Add this line:

    `""%PHPBIN%" "D:\AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\phpunit.phar" %*`
13. Repeat point 9.
14. if it still doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it works well. Just the `.cmd` or `.bat` didn't worked, I should wrote `phpunit.cmd` to run the command. Why don't you just rename `phpunit.phar` to `phpunit` ?