# PHPUnit Installation on WAMP gives error

Tags: php, phpunit, wampserver

I'm following below post

[How to install PHPUnit with WAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305190/how-to-install-phpunit-with-wamp/31625378)

http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2011/04/installing-phpunit-on-windows.html

But i'm still getting error as below mentioned

```
D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de Discovering channel pear.phpunit.de over http:// failed with message: channel-ad d: Cannot open "http://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml" (File http://pear.phpunit.de :80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone )) Trying to discover channel pear.phpunit.de over https:// instead Discovery of channel "pear.phpunit.de" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https:/ /pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml" (File https://pear.phpunit.de:443/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone )))

D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit Attempting to discover channel "phpunit"... Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "phpunit"... unknown channel "phpunit" in "phpunit/PHPUnit" invalid package name/package file "phpunit/PHPUnit" install failed
```

Unable to find PEAR_ENV.reg file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Install PHP UNIT](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) and in that **windows** section.
:) This may useful to you...